# Is database updated at the time of updating an App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I have an App in my Device, that contains database, if I update that app from the App Store, then database of App will be updated or it uses the same database of previous App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you stored your data in `NSDocumentDirectory` or `NSLibraryDirectory`, your data are still there after updating your app and until the app is deleted.

Comment: Yes I am using NSDocumentDirectory, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The database of app will be updated only and only if you have modified the .sqlite file in your app and then you are replacing the previous one with the same name. Hope it helps!